# Symfony2 get current environment in response listener

Tags: symfony

I'd like to know if I'm using app_dev.php from within a listener (set up as a service in `config.yml`).  It fails at getEnvironment() though this is the method I use in the controller.

```
public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event) {
    $kernel = $event->getKernel();
    $this->isAppDev = ($kernel->getEnvironment() == "dev") ? true : false;
}
```

Edit **Solution**:
In my listener class:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response; 
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
private $kernel;
public function __construct(Kernel $kernel) {
    $this->kernel = $kernel
}
public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event) {
    $this->isAppDev = ($this->kernel->getEnvironment() == "dev") ? true : false;
}
```

At the bottom of config.yml:

```
services:
   my.listener:
       class: Path\To\Listener
       tags:
           - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response }
       arguments: [@kernel]
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[$event->getKernel()](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Event/KernelEvent.php#L31) returns an object which implements [HttpKernelInterface](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernelInterface.php). Whereas [Kernel](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php) or `AppKernel` implements [KernelInterface](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/KernelInterface.php) which have `getEnvironment` method. You have to inject `@kernel` service in your listener.